# Numpyでの列追加について

Tags: python, numpy

以下で定義した配列に対し、全列に対し、"0"を追加したいのですが、
どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

```py
(0を追加する前)
arr = np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9] ])
arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

```py
やりたいこと
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0],
       [7, 8, 9, 0]])
```

```py
insertを使うと、一次元配列になってしまう。
かつ、0は1回目しか入らない
np.insert(arr,3,0)
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: [numpy.c_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html)を使って、`np.c_[arr, [0]*arr.shape[0]]` など。

Comment: なるほど、出来ました！！

Comment: ちなみに、1,2,3,0,0したい場合は、np.c_[arr, [[0,0]]*arr.shape[0]]とすれば出来ますね。参考になります。

Answer (score 1):

```
np.insert(arr, 3, 0, axis=1)
```

とすると

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0],
       [7, 8, 9, 0]])
```

が得られます。
np.insert(arr, 3, 0, axis=1)の
0は追加する値
axis=1は列として追加
3は3列目だと思うのですが、私も不慣れなのでうまく説明できません。

Comment: axis : int, optional

Comment: Axis along which to insert values. If axis is None then arr is flattened first.

Comment: なるほど、axis=1が必要だったんですね。。。